# C++ execute function after constructors before main

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, static, atexit

Question: is there a way to tell GCC to call a function before `main()` but after all constructors (including `__attribute__ ((constructor))` and globally scoped static variables)?

Background: I have a shared library which needs to automatically provide some capability on loading and clean up after itself on exit. The "on loading" functionality is handled by defining a set of functions with `__attribute__ ((constructor))`. These constructor functions may interact with globally scoped static variables. Some of these constructor functions may further register `atexit()` handler to take care of the cleanup requirement. The catch is that my exit handler needs to access those static variables. Unfortunately, some of those static variables are declared an inner scopes (e.g. inside functions), which means that their destructors get called **before** the exit handler. This results in "use after free" type functionality.

The easiest way to demonstrate this problem is with the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  public:
    A()  { std::cout << "A ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "A dtor" << std::endl; }
    void doit() { std::cout << "Exit handler cleanup" << std::endl; }
};

static A a;

static void my_handler()
{
  a.doit();
}

__attribute__ ((constructor)) void prepare_exit_handler(void)
{
  printf("Foo constructor function\n");
  atexit(my_handler);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Start of main" << std::endl;
  exit(1);
}
```

When executed, this outputs

```
Foo constructor function
A ctor
Start of main
A dtor
Exit handler cleanup
```

The last line of the output shows that `a.doit()` is executed *after* `a` is destructed.

One possibility I considered was to use `init_priroty` attribute to force the `atexit()` call to happen after all static variables are instantiated, thus guaranteeing the exit handler will get executed before static variable destructors.

```cpp
__attribute__ ((constructor)) __attribute__ ((init_priority (65535))) void prepare_exit_handler(void)
```

However, this causes a compile time error

```
error: can only use ‘init_priority’ attribute on file-scope definitions of objects of class type
```

**UPDATE 1** - apparently the correct way to specify init priority for constructors is with `__attribute__ ((constructor(65535)))`. However, even the last priority (highest legal number, 65535) appears to be *before* static constructors are called.

**UPDATE 2** - I think I found the magic combination of attributes which works as desired. There is one downfall - it requires explicitly specifying `init_priority` on all of my static variables. Is there a way around that limitation?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  public:
    A()  { printf("A ctor\n"); }
    ~A() { printf("A dtor\n"); }
    void doit() { std::cout << "Exit handler cleanup" << std::endl; }
};

static __attribute__ ((init_priority(1001))) A a;

static void my_handler()
{
  a.doit();
}

__attribute__ ((constructor(65535))) void prepare_exit_handler(void)
{
  printf("Registering atexit\n");
  atexit(my_handler);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Start of main" << std::endl;
  exit(1);
}
```

which produces

```
A ctor
Registering atexit
Start of main
Exit handler cleanup
A dtor
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo - The background section in the post is quite extensive. Did you have a specific question about my use case?

Comment: I think I lost it Paul. Sorry.